# Is it possible to create a console in JavaScript that provides a persistent local scope?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'd like to create a console (think chrome's dev console), in JavaScript for a web application, that has a persistent scope. So you would be able to say, set a variable, and then access that variable later in the console. Is there an easy way to do this in JavaScript?

An example session:

```
var x = SomeCustomFunction()
>> "the result"
x.slice(4)
>> "result"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use indirect calls to `eval`.

Direct calls won't work because they would use the calling execution context, which will probably change between creating the variable and attempting to access it.

Instead, indirect calls to `eval` will use the global execution context, and thus the variables will persist.

Some ways to make indirect calls to `eval` are using `var myEval = eval; myEval(...)` or `window.eval(...)`.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
    data = document.getElementById('data');
document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function() {
  var code = input.value,
      result = window.eval(code);
  data.appendChild(document.createElement('dt')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
  data.appendChild(document.createElement('dd')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(result));
  return false;
};
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <dl id="data"></dl>
  <input id="input" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

For example, in the snippet above, enter `var x = 5`. Then enter `x`, and you will receive `5`.

Comment: This `eval` is not isolated from your application code.  As such, using the console could break it (destroy application state.)

Comment: @RickHitchcock Because indirect calls to eval behave different than direct calls. See [§10.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2)

Comment: @NoahFreitas True. I only wanted to provide a simple approach, but it can be improved by running the code in another window, and also by adding `try...catch` to catch errors, adding a pretty display of objects, ...

Comment: @Oriol, so setting a variable to `eval` is enough to make it "indirect"? So it sounds like an "indirect" call to eval executes it in global scope, is that right?

Comment: @BT Yes, a direct call to `eval` would create the variable in the scope of the `submit` event listener (and thus wouldn't be shared among different calls to it). Storing `eval` in a variable or using `window.eval` produces an indirect call which will run in global scope.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using an `eval`-based implementation, you could create an iframe to create a separate execution context.  You could then use its global `eval` function to evaluate expressions in an isolated execution context.  The context will preserve state between evaluations.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

// We have to attach the iframe to the document to get a new execution context.
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

// Now the console implementation is simply the context's eval function.
var myConsole = iframe.contentWindow.eval;

myConsole('function SomeCustomFunction() { return "the result"; }');
myConsole('var x = SomeCustomFunction()'); // "the result"
myConsole('x.slice(4)'); // "result"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly what you asked for.

You can develop a Google Chrome Extension using the devtools.inspectedWindow API https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index#stable_apis.

"Use the chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow API to interact with the inspected window: obtain the tab ID for the inspected page, evaluate the code in the context of the inspected window, reload the page, or obtain the list of resources within the page."

Your scope is bound to the page.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// create object
var obj = {};
// define property `console`
obj.console = {};
// define `log` property of `obj.console`
obj.console.log = function(name, args) { 
  // if `obj.console.log` called without `args`
  // and `name` defined at `obj` , return `obj[name]`
  // else set `obj[name]`  , return  `obj[name]`
  if (name !== undefined && args === undefined && obj[name]) return obj[name]
  else obj.setProps(name, args); return obj[name]
};

obj.setProps = function setProps(name, args) {
  // if `name` is not reserved `"log"` , set `obj[name]` to `args`
  // persist `obj[name]` at local scope of `obj`
  if (!this[name] && name !== "log") this[name] = args;
}

function SomeCustomFunction() {
  return "the result"
}

var x = SomeCustomFunction();

// do stuff
obj.console.log("x", x);

console.log(obj.console.log("x"));

console.log(obj.console.log("x").slice(4));

// set `y` 
console.log(obj.console.log("y", Math.random() * 1000).toFixed(5));

console.log(obj.console.log("y"));

// set `obj` properties globally
// for (prop in obj) if (prop !== "log" && !window[prop]) window[prop] = obj[prop]
```